# creating active records objects with sidekiq

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq

i would like to create active record objects with sidekiq. i know it's not best practice, because i have to serializing the entire object, but in this case there is no other option.

if i try it out i get:

```
  EventTrackingWorker JID-ec2be02dae626dd19202b17f INFO: start
  EventTrackingWorker JID-ec2be02dae626dd19202b17f INFO: fail: 0.033 sec
  WARN: {"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"EventTrackingWorker", "args"=>["shift_created_event", {... long json object ..}}, "create"], "jid"=>"ec2be02dae626dd19202b17f"}
  WARN: undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class
  WARN: /Users/jedi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:366:in `primary_key'
  /Users/jedi/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194-perf/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:216:in `association_primary_key'
```

the error says: **WARN: undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class**

the object (an event in this case) which is created with this method:

```
Track(:shift_created_event, {eventable: @shift, creator: current_user})
```

the **Track** method looks like this:

```
module EventTracking
  module_function

  def Track(event, options, method=:create)
    EventTrackingWorker.perform_async(event, options, method)
  end

end
```

the `EventTrackingWorker` class:

```
class EventTrackingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(event, options, method=:create)
    event.to_s.classify.constantize.new(options).send(method)
  end

end
```

note: `event.to_s.classify.constantize.new(options).send(method)` converts the string `shift_created_event`to an active record class `ShiftCreatedEvent`and calls `new`with options. after that i create the object with `.send(method)`

does someone have some experience with that ?

Comment: Can you show us the code in addition to the error?  At least a sample - currently it's not clear what you're doing or what you've tried.

Comment: yeah, sorry. i updated the question.

Comment: I think you need to figure out which hash is getting sent the #primary_key method.  I suspect it's something in your serialized json (related objects on @shift perhaps, e.g. something in 'options') that is not getting re-inflated properly.  Generally in my experience it's best to handle object creation synchronously and leave the async work for jobs that actually take a long time.

Comment: mh ok. but creating active records objects "should" work right ? i gonna try to use simpler objects and debug from there...

Comment: Yeah, it's not the creation that's the problem, it's probably the associated objects that are getting serialized/deserialized improperly.  You make your life easier if you just pass ids around.  :)

Comment: i have done that in some other workers. i try to use sidekiq here to improve controller response time. the events are created in e.g. in the controller#create action.